# Does there exist a sequence $(a_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|a_n-a_m|=(n-m)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ for all natural numbers $n\geq m$?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a sequence $(a_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|a_n-a_m|=(n-m)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ for all natural numbers $n\geq m$?

I tried by choosing $n=m+1$ but I am not getting.

Comment: What are you not getting?

Comment: It seems unlikely. You need $a_{m}$ and $a_{m+2}$ to be distance $1$ from $a_{m+1}$ and $a_m$ and $a_{m+2}$ to be distance $2^{1/4}.$ So every three consecutive points determine a congruent triangle. I bet there is no way to pick even $a_4$ such that $a_2,a_3,a_4$ have this configuration with $|a_1-a_4|=3^{1/4}.$

Comment: So if we write in complex numbers notation, we can pick $a_1=1,a_2=0,a_3=a+bi.$ Then you must have either $a_4=-a_3^2+a_3$ or $-1+a_3.$ Either way, the distance between $a_4$ and $a_1=1$ with not be $3^{1/4}.$

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "no".

Indeed, take four successive terms, for example $a_0...a_3$ and denote the distance between $a_n$ and $a_m$ by $d_{mn}$.

Use [Cayley-Menger determinant relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) :

$$\begin{vmatrix}0&d_{01}^{2}&d_{02}^{2}&d_{03}^{2}&1\\
d_{01}^{2}&0&d_{12}^{2}&d_{13}^{2}&1\\
d_{02}^{2}&d_{12}^{2}&0&d_{23}^{2}&1\\d_{03}^{2}&d_{13}^{2}&d_{23}^{2}&0&1\\1&1&1&1&0\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Otherwise said :

$$\begin{vmatrix}0&1&\sqrt{2}&\sqrt{3}&1\\
1&0&1&\sqrt{2}&1\\
\sqrt{2}&1&0&1&1\\\sqrt{3}&\sqrt{2}&1&0&1\\1&1&1&1&0\end{vmatrix}=0$$

bringing a contradiction because the LHS is equal to $8(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})+4 \ne 0$.

Comment: A similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3758649/305862)

Comment: Why don't you attempt to make any comment on solutions that are provided to you ? This was already the case some days ago for this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4644191/305862) and my answer.